# Javascript Discord bot code which will send a embed when ping is written

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When a user sends a message "ping", the bot should reply with an embed "pong". I am a starter. The code I have made is given below:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('ping!')) {
    message.reply('pong!');
  }
});

client.on('ready', () => {
   console.log('I am ready!'); 
});

client.login('your bot token');
```

Comment: You can view the docs for embeds [Here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a new [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed), set some properties such as [`MessageEmbed.color`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=color) and [`MessageEmbed.description`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=description), and send it to a [`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel).

---

```js
// Listening to "message" event.
client.on("message", message => {
    // Checking if the lowercase message equals "ping".
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "ping") {
        // Creating a new MessageEmbed Class.
        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

        Embed.setDescription("pong");
        Embed.setColor("RED");

        // Replying with the embed.
        message.reply(Embed);
    }
});
```